# What would be the Alias for this 'User Edit' page link?

Tags: views, path-aliases

Working on a User Dashboard (using the Workbench Module), I have a link in a Views Block which the user can click to 'edit' their details. The current link looks messy (as shown below) and I would like to use an Alias to give a much more attractive frontend link Edit profile to reflect the page link and not the one as shown below. 
The current path links from the 'Edit Link' field in an Account Views Block and I'm using a 'Rewrite' as user/[name] within the path of the said field.

However, currently changing the link in Alias module gives me multiple errors trying with the likes of 'user/edit' path, what am I doing wrong, or is it an issue with Workbench?

[http://localhost/sitename/user/46/edit?destination=admin/workbench]

Answer (score 0):

please check this module, which should do the job for you

https://drupal.org/project/path_alias_xt

> Extended Path Aliases finishes the job left incomplete by core's Path
>   module, fixing all of the above. And it does so automatically, without
>   any configuration options or permissions to set and without requiring
>   any other modules. Just install and you're away.

Comment: Thank you for the lead, I will install and get back to you later with results. I thought I was going mad! LOL I'm a Drupal 'plumber' so need all the Drupal widgets I can get.